# Focus on textbox not working

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a main window with a content control that hosts other pages.  One of the pages has a textbox and a gridview.  When that page loads I want to set focus on the textbox.  If I do this in the code-behind, the box doesn't get focus.  If I do this in XAML for the page using

```
FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=DrugScanTextBox}"
```

then I can see the cursor in the textbox but it isn't blinking and keypresses do not show in the box.

My only guess is that the focus is being taken by the gridview after it loads and draws the data.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I added a boolean property 'FocusNow' and set it to true at the end of my background worker's loaded event, then added this border style around the user control.  This way, AFTER everything is done loading, it sets the focus to the grid (in your case textbox).

```
<Border Margin="10" >
    <Border.Style>
        <Style>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding FocusNow}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="FocusManager.FocusedElement" Value="{Binding ElementName=xamDataGrid1}" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Border.Style>
```

.
.
.

Comment: I tried something similar using an event but it didn't really change anything.  There has to be a better way to do this...